# I am getting the error while connecting django to mongodb database using djongo

Tags: python, django, mongodb, djongo

I am trying to create dynamic website using Django.For dynamic data i have tried to use mongodb Database.For the connection between mongo db and django ,djongo is used here.

After defining the database and tried to the command makemigrations it shows the error.

Data definition in Settings file.py

`DATABASES = { 'default': { 'ENGINE': 'djongo', 'NAME': 'Cake_Bakery', 'CLIENT':{'host':'localhost','port':27017} } }`

error is given below:

```
(cake) PS D:\Cake Eccomerce\cake\Cake_Bakery> python manage.py makemigrations
    System check identified some issues:

    WARNINGS:
    ?: (urls.W002) Your URL pattern '/products' [name='products'] has a route beginning with a '/'.             Remove this slash as it is unnecessary. If this pattern is targeted in an include(), ensure the include() pattern has a trailing '/'.
     No changes detected
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "D:\Cake Eccomerce\cake\Cake_Bakery\manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
     File "D:\Cake Eccomerce\cake\Cake_Bakery\manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
     File "D:\Cake Eccomerce\cake\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 446,   in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "D:\Cake Eccomerce\cake\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 440, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "D:\Cake Eccomerce\cake\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 415, in run_from_argv
    connections.close_all()
  File "D:\Cake Eccomerce\cake\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\connection.py", line 85, in close_all
    conn.close()
  File "D:\Cake Eccomerce\cake\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\Cake Eccomerce\cake\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 358, in    close
    self._close()
  File "D:\Cake Eccomerce\cake\Lib\site-packages\djongo\base.py", line 208, in _close
    if self.connection:
  File "D:\Cake Eccomerce\cake\Lib\site-packages\pymongo\database.py", line 1337, in __bool__
    raise NotImplementedError(
NotImplementedError: Database objects do not implement truth value testing or bool(). Please compare with None instead: database is not None
(cake) PS D:\Cake Eccomerce\cake\Cake_Bakery>
```

How to rectify the above error .

djongo version used here is :1.3.6v
django version used here is 4.1.13v
mongo db downloaded version is :7.0.3

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the new version of pymongo (4.0 from 29.11.2021) which is not supported by Djongo 1.3.6. You need to install pymongo 3.12.1.

Install pymongo version

```
pip install pymongo==3.12.1
```